# Excel - Sum of data at equal intervals

Tags: excel, sum

I have some time series longitude latitude data which I am trying to sum up for each month. ( 4 x column headings Time, long, lat, precipitation).

Is there a way of summing data automatically for regular intervals or do I have to manually update the sum equation code cell?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks

I have tried summing it manually but due to large data mass this will take along time.

Comment: What about sumifs() and have one for each month?

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily find the month number of a date, using the `=Month()` worksheet function. Adding such a column might give you the possibility to use the basic "Subtotals" feature of Excel, as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]